# Button redirection response based on value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a code for url direction based on values given in the text field. If the value in username and password is test - the page should be directed [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). If some other value is entered, it should display on the same page an error message.

```
<label for="uname">Username:</label>
<input type="text"  id="uname" name="uname" value=""> <br>
<label for="pwd">Password:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="pwd"  name="pwd" value=""><br>
<button class="login" onsubmit="redirectPage()">Login</button> 
                
<script>
function redirectPage(uname,pwd)
{
if (uname == 'test' and pwd=='test')
{window.location = "http://www.google.com";}
else
document.write("The code is wrong, try again!")
}
            </script>
```

I know the code is horribly wrong, but I am trying to learn something new.

Comment: I hope this is only to test and learn and not a real password access you try to do. Dont forget JS on client side is not a safe place.

Comment: Oh yes, this is just to learn how this functionality works ! Im trying to design a dummy website where my team can learn automation testing.. https://trytestingthis.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of `uname` and `pwd` and then called redirectPage function.

```js
function redirectPage(uname, pwd) {
  if (uname === "test" && pwd === "test") {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
  } else {
    document.write("The code is wrong, try again!");
  }
}

document.querySelector("#handleOnSubmit").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const uname = document.querySelector("#uname").value;
  const pwd = document.querySelector("#pwd").value;

  redirectPage(uname, pwd);
});
```

```html
<label for="uname">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="">
<br />
<br />
<label for="pwd">Password:</label>
<input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd" value=""><br>
<button class="login" id="handleOnSubmit">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

---

```js
function redirectPage() {
  var uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
  var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd').value
    if (uname== 'test' && pwd== 'test') {
       window.location = "https://www.google.com";
    } else {
      document.write("The code is wrong, try again!")
    } 
  }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="redirectPage()">
<label for="uname">Username:</label>
<input type="text"  id="uname" name="uname" value=""> <br>
<label for="pwd">Password:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="pwd"  name="pwd" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the field, cause the variables are not transferred as parameters.

```
<script>
  function redirectPage() {
    if (document.getElementById('uname').value == 'test' && document.getElementById('pwd').value == 'test') {
       window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    } else {
      document.write("The code is wrong, try again!")
    } 
  }              
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript as mentioned below:

```js
function ValidateUser() {
  if (document.getElementById("uname").value == 'test' && document.getElementById("pwd").value == 'test') {
    window.open("https://www.google.com");
  } else {
    document.write("The code is wrong, try again")
  }
}
```

With the HTML as:

```html
<label for="uname">UserName:</label>
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname">
<br>
<label for="pwd">Password:</label>
<input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd">
<br>
<button id="btnLogin" onclick="ValidateUser();">Login</button>
```

Or you can use `jQuery` to achieve the same with the two code snippets shown below:

```js
function ValidateUser() {
  if ($("#uname").val() == 'test' && $("#pwd").val() == 'test') {
    window.open("https://www.google.com");
  } else {
    document.write("The code is wrong, try again")
  }
}
```

Or:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnLogin").click(function() {
    if ($("#uname").val() == 'test' && $("#pwd").val() == 'test') {
      window.open("https://www.google.com");
    } else {
      document.write("The code is wrong, try again")
    }
  })
});
```

With a slight change in HTML:

```html
<label for="uname">UserName:</label>
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname">
<br>
<label for="pwd">Password:</label>
<input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd">
<br>
<button id="btnLogin">Login</button>
```